# count or bool of child records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Would like to return count of child records for each record in results?

```
lists
listid,name
----------------
1,foods
2,fruits
3,veggies
4,counties
5,blah /* other list types */


listitems
listid,listitemId,listname
----------------
1,1,fruits
2,1,veggies
3,3,carrots
4,3,broccoli
```

Here's the query I have to work with:

```
declar @listid int
select @listid = 1 --as an example
select * from listitems where listid=@listid

results:
1,1,fruits
2,1,veggies
```

**Goal:
I'd like to display the count of items that exist for fruits and veggies in this example**

```
listitems
listitemid,listid,name,childcount
1,1,fruits,0
2,1,veggies,2
```

Here's how I came up with the answer:

```
select *,
(
    select (select case when COUNT(*)>0 then 1 else 0 end as reccount 
    from ListItems li3 where li3.listid = l.listid) 
    from Lists l where li2.name = l.listname
) as haschildrecords
 from ListItems li2 where listid=1
```

I am still deciding if I want to return a count or bit...

Is this correct or the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *,
(
    select (select case when COUNT(*)>0 then 1 else 0 end as reccount 
    from ListItems li3 where li3.listid = l.listid) 
    from Lists l where li2.name = l.listname
) as haschildrecords
 from ListItems li2 where listid=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
select
  lists.listid,
  lists.name, 
  count(distinct listitemid) as itemcount, 
  convert(bit,sign(count(distinct listitemid) ) ) as itemexists    
from
  lists 
     left join
  listitems on lists.listid = listitems. listid
group by 
  lists.listid,lists.name
```

I can't tell, but if you're constructing a hierarchical structure, then you'll want to look at `common table expressions`, and/or `HierarchyID`

Comment: i can't tell either, something i inherited.

Comment: please see Goal section in original post for desired results.